# Why is it impossible to invert the analytic continuation of a Dirichlet series?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

By Mathematica (and the truncated Euler MacLaurin formula) I know that:

$$\zeta(s)=\lim_{k\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{(s-1) k^{s-1}}\right) \tag{1}$$
when the real part of $s$ is greater than $0$.

**Question:**

> I would like to understand better why it is impossible to find a
>   Dirichlet series for the reciprocal of the Right Hand Side (RHS) of $(1)$.

In other words I am looking for to invert the reciprocal of the Riemann zeta function:

$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\frac{1}{\lim_{k\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{(s-1) k^{s-1}}\right)} \tag{2}$$
when the real part of $s$ is greater than $0$.

For $\Re(s)>1$ there is the well known relation:

$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} \tag{3}$$

and the Riemann hypothesis is that $(3)$ converges for $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$.

In a sense I already know the answer to the question. It is because $\frac{1}{(s-1) k^{s-1}}$ is like a constant and $\sum _{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^s}$ is the Dirichlet series. But can you explain it better to me?

Comment: If there was such a Dirichlet series for the reciprocal of the RHS of $(1)$ then a formula for the Riemann zeta zeros would follow after some effort. One could perhaps say that there is no formula for the zeta zeros because the RHS of $(3)$ is an epsilon away from converging on the critical line.

Comment: You should look at the Dirichlet L-function $\beta(s) = \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n (2n+1)^{-s}$. It converges for $\Re(s) > 0$ and iff it has no zeros for $\Re(s) > \sigma$ then $\frac{1}{\beta(s)}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (2n+1)^{-s} \mu(n)$ for $\Re(s) >\sigma$. For $\Re(s)$ large enough $\frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n (2n+1)^{-s}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n (2n+1)^{-s})^k$, once reordered it is a Dirichlet series. It shouldn't converge beyond $\Re(s) > 1$. For $\zeta$ those things won't be Dirichlet series anymore due to the additional term $\frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1}$.

Comment: Also the [explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function) for $\sum_{n \le x} \mu(n)$ tell us how to regularize/continue $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n)n^{-s}$ to any vertical strip with no zeros.